# Load JS file from URL and wait till it's finished executed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

### Problem:

I'm trying to load a javascript file from an external URL in a create-react-app. I require this javascript file to finish loading and executing before react begins rendering the root component.

This is because I require something this javascript file puts on the window object further down the component tree. I do not control this javascript file, unfortunately, but require it.

The URL for this file varies for each environment (dev, staging, prod etc.). The build process currently builds the create-react-app once and then the package is promoted through each environment. I get the relative URL from a JSON file which I load at the very beginning of the application.

### Attempted solution(s)

I have tried using `react-helmet`, which allows me to modify the URL at runtime but I need the loading/interpreting of the JS file to complete before moving on.
This blocking/loading timing is something I can't seem to control.

I also tried manually adding the script tag before the `RenderDom.Render` call with it wrapped in promise. This is not working.

Can anyone give me some guidance on how to tackle this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25701083/how-to-add-callback-after-dynamically-loading-javascript-file

Answer (score 0):

try `react-script-loader-hoc`.

This gives you a `HOC` where you can call this `HOC` with your component as `param`. This will give you a prop `scriptsLoadedSuccessfully`. If this is `true` then your script has loaded.

Below is the example:

```
function YourComponent ({ scriptsLoadedSuccessfully }) {
   if (scriptsLoadedSuccessfully){
      return <div>Script loaded do your stuff here.</div>
   } else {
      return <div>Script not loaded wait until it gets loaded.</div>
   }
}

export default ScriptLoader('http://YOUR_SCRIPT_URL')(YourComponent);
```