# How can I wait until a newly created Element is "ready" (all scripts downloaded)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I'm working on a piece of code that glues Sammy JS (router) and Knockout JS together.

So, this is my problem,

```html
<script id="MyTemplate" type="text/html"> 
    // [HTML Containing a script link (Encoded HTML)]
</script>`
```

I use jQuery to create an instance of this template :

```js
var TInstance = $($("#MyTemplate").text())
```

Then, I want to inject the new html `TInstance` into my `<body>` or an other existing tag

```js
$("body").html(TInstance)
```

All Good, now I want to do `ko.applyBindings` to bind the new `TInstance` to an `ViewModel` and it works.

The problem I have is: when I have an `<script src="..." />` inside `TInstance`,
 I want to wait until that script is downloaded and parsed, then do `ko.applyBindings`.

So I tried `$(TInstance).ready(() => {ko.applyBindings(...)})`, It works the first time the page loaded, but if I redo the whole process, swapping in a new `TInstance` the ready handler on the new `TInstance` won't fire.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this answer will not be "copy & paste and play", it will require some tweaking from you, but i think you will get the concept and you will manage.

Without adding a dependency management module, and without restructuring you code ( usually plain script tags don't get injected dynamically along with html for the same reason you have troubles right now. Its a good idea to load script tags with html for the first page load, but any content added later on, especially if some flow is required, will need programmatic handling, hence the need for module management frameworks for larger projects)

One way to do it is to stop your code execution flow and poll the enviroment to see if your script is loaded. i.e:

```
    var demoInterval = setInterval(function(){          
        if(myCondition){
            clearInterval(demoInterval );
            functionThatStartsTheRestOfTheLogicFlow();  // this could apply bindings etc etc
        }
    },50);
```

Now for example, if you where loading jQuery with the script tag your condition could be
    typeof($) !== 'undefined'
It would poll every 50 milliseconds until $ is defined, and then it would call a function to clear the polling and continue your logic flow.

In your case the condition could be the definition of a function/model, a flag-like variable that your custom js file can set and the polling would expect to read at some point etc etc.

Even better would be to remove the script tag from the html and load the script dynamically by javascript so that you can utilize the onload event of the specific script that is required, you can read an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25701083/how-to-add-callback-after-dynamically-loading-javascript-file). Programatically controlling these cases is much easier for the developer.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

have resolved the problem by using a 0ms `setTimeout` call

```
setTimeout(() => { /*all new resources have been loaded and the html rendered*/ });
```

Help: https://eager.io/blog/how-to-decide-when-your-code-should-run/

Comment: i am not really sure this will solve your problem. You might have solved it when developing locally, but this might not work properly for users that do not talk to local servers and have to pay time costs to download resources. setTimeout does nothing to guarantee that the resources you wanted will be loaded on time, all it does is push some operations later on. You need a strict handling of when things are loaded and you are ready to go, instead of "guessing how much time to wait is good enough" as this will vary from user to user

Comment: Yes, that's true.Please give an better solution if you can, I'm still looking to improve mine. Thanks.

Comment: do you have some kind of framework to manage dependencies? like requirejs, webpack or smthing? If not you will have to manually sync those actions with javascript, it might not look pretty but it will get the job done..

Comment: No, no module management tool or..., just MVC 4 on backend and plain Js files.Can you please elaborate on the "do it with js" part, Thanks.

Comment: Ok. is the script some specific library or is is some custom js file?

Comment: I Guess i should crawl the html, collect all script tags and download them manually, right?

Comment: Custom js, along with jQuery for DOM manipulation + KO and Sammy Js(vannila router)